# Does sandboxing allow my application to tap Quartz events?

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

According to the author of [this software](http://smilesoftware.com/textexpander/faq.html):

`TextExpander cannot be "sandboxed" according to the latest restrictions from Apple`

Here is what TextExpander does:

`TextExpander saves your fingers and your keyboard, expanding custom keyboard shortcuts into frequently-used text`

What does that mean exactly ? I would like to react to Quartz events and post Quartz events  accordingly.

Comment: What does keyboard shortcuts and Quartz have in common?

Comment: By keyboard shortcuts, the author actually means completion shortcuts expanding to predefined snippets.

Comment: But how does that relate to Quartz?  Why even mention it.

Comment: @trojanfoe Because it's [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html)' event tap mechanism that would enable an app to listen to the keyboard while in the background.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look possible use `CGEventTap` within sandboxed app.  This [Apple Developer Forum thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/742845#742845) shows some details.

Comment: CGEventTap can be used inside a sandboxed app - but only for events delivered to the app itself, not for events delivered to external apps.